# White screen - Flutter IOS app on test flight - white screen for few user but runs perfectly for other users

Tags: flutter, screen, testflight, white-framework

Flutter IOS app on test flight - white screen for few user but runs perfectly for other users. Before uploading the IOS app to TestFlight on simulator the app runs perfectly. When I upload the IOS app on TestFlight for 4 user. Then 2 user are able to run the app perfectly but the other two are not able to run the app and gets "white screen".

For Iphone 14 pro max user not seeing the IOS app but iPhone 13 / iPhone 11 Pro Max user is seeing the app and it runs perfectly.

Any help greatly appreciated

Things I tried.

1. Removed all the error shown in flutter problem screen like - removed null error, remove all the warnings
2. I completed the whole cycle like flutter clean / flutter run / flutter build ios --release but no solution to my problem
3. I updated the target IOS to 15 from 12 earlier but no solution

Comment: Check "Forced Null Values" and "IncorrectParentData"(Expanded,Flex).

Comment: can you please elborate

Comment: On screens where your users receive errors, check the following:

Nullable and '!' your variables used with (someVariable!.chainOther etc.),

Check for widgets such as Expanded or Flex that are used incorrectly or may have constrained errors.


In particular, compare the data of your users with errors with those of users who do not, and confirm whether there is a data-related error.

Finally, run your application in profile mode on iPhone 14 Pro Max and try to catch errors.

Comment: Its not solved the problem